# Find records in database that repeat within a time span

Tags: mysql

I have a series of records in MySQL that represent troubleshooting events for devices. I'm interesting in finding which devices have consecutive troubleshooting events within a given time span.

For example, I want to know when two or more troubleshooting events occurred within 5 days of each other, but I'm not sure how to construct the query to list all devices.

I have two tables similar to this:

```
devices
-----
id    name

events
-----
id    device_id    datetime
```

With this sample data:

```
events
-----
id    device_id    datetime
---   ---          ---
1     1            2011-01-01
2     1            2011-06-15
3     2            2011-06-18
4     1            2011-06-18
5     2            2011-06-20
```

I would like to construct a query that provides a result like:

```
device_id    event_id    datetime
1            2           2011-06-15
1            4           2011-06-18
2            3           2011-06-18
2            5           2011-06-20
```

Since the event on 2011-01-01 is isolated by more than 5 days, it should be omitted.

I would appreciate pointers on how to approach this.

Comment: A related question but with events having a date range themselves: [Select repeat occurrences within time period <x days](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7452157/161052)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a WAG.

```
select
  device_id,
  event_id,
  datetime
from
  events
where
  device_id in
(
  select
    device_id
  from
  (
    select
      device_id,
      count(device_id) event_count
    from
      events
    group by
      device_id
    having
      event_count > 1
  )
)
order by
  device_id,
  event_id,
  datetime
```

possibly
`where
  event_count > 1`
instead of the having.

For the date range, add the range check to the inner most query (the one with the count()).

For example, add (snipped from another answer):
`WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()`

Comment: How does this relate to the date range requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT devices.`device_id`, events.`id` AS event_id, events.`datetime`
FROM devices
INNER JOIN events ON events.`id` = devices.`id`
WHERE events.`datetime` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY devices.`device_id` ASC
```

This would find all the devices that had events withi the last 5 days. You could replace both `CURDATE()` with any start date.

Comment: This would list all events in the date range, but I'm interested in *repeat* events. Single events for a device within the date range should be omitted.